# Appropriate test for independence of predictor variables in logistic regression

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, independence, variance-inflation-factor

I want to test for independence between 7 categorical predictor variables in a logistic regression model. I believe the appropriate test would be a chi-square test, but I have 7 variables - is there a "better" test to use if I have more than two variables?

Comment: Why do you need to "test for independence" among those predictor variables? What would change in your modeling based on the test results? It's seldom that predictor variables are "independent" of each other in practice, yet modeling is still quite possible.

Comment: I normally use the vif function to test for multicollinearity among continuous predictor variables. From what I’ve read, the vif function cannot be used on categorical variables; however, I read that a chi-square test can be used instead to test for multicollinearity among predictor variables. Further reading suggested that a chi-square test does not test for multicollinearity, but independence. Is this incorrect?

Comment: But why do you care about their independence? What would you change if the variables lacked independence? If they were weakly related? If they were strongly related?

Comment: There are different versions of vif, and some will work for categorical variables. See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185969/how-can-we-calculate-the-variance-inflation-factor-for-a-categorical-predictor-v, and the paper  https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.14590